# I'm having trouble understanding an intuitive derivation of the Thomas precession formula

Tags: special-relativity

I found an articled called "On the Thomas Precession of Accelerated Axes", by Dancoff and Inglis, which gives a quick derivation of the thomas precession, but I seem to be stuck on one of the steps.

The article considers the rest frame of an electron, called P, and the rest frame of the nucleus, called N. It then introduces 2 references frames, P' (moving with velocity $\vec v$ with respect to N) and P'' (moving with velocity $\vec u$ with respect to N), such that at time $t$ P coincides with P' and at time $t+\mathrm{d}t$ P coincides with P''. P is not inertial but P' and P'' are.

P' and N have parallel axes (with $\vec v$ on the x axis), and so do P'' and P'. The objective is then proving that N and P'' don't have parallel axes. This is done by showing that the $x$ axis from N forms an angle $\phi$ with $\vec u$, while the $x''$ axis from P'' forms a different angle $\phi''$ with $\vec u$. It then shows that

$$\phi \approx \tan \phi =\frac{u_y}{u_x}=\frac{u_y'}{\gamma v}$$

using the relativistic velocity addition formulae from frame P' to N:

$$ u_x=\frac{u_x'+v}{1-\frac{vu_x'}{c^2}}, \quad u_y=\frac{u_y'}{\gamma\left(1-\frac{vu_x'}{c^2}\right)} $$

Up to this point I understand. However, the next step is calculating $\phi''\approx u_y''/u_x''$, and the authors simply claim that this is equal to $u_y'/v$. They say that, to arrive at this result, I need to transform $\vec v$ from frame P' to frame P''. I've done this, along with several other attempts, and I cannot arrive at that result. Am I missing something here?